# Is it possible to log or handle automatic kafka producer retries when acks=all

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I know I can set `acks=all` in Kafka producer configuration to make producer to wait for acknowledgement from leader after all replicas receive the message sent. If the acknowledgement timeout occurs, producer retries sending message. This happens transparently without requiring any code changes. Is it possible to have some stats of those retries. Is it possible to know which message involved retries and how many retries. Does Kafka provide any kind of hook to be called before / after retry so that we can log some message?

Comment: this is a very good question. are you getting some log messages from the producer's console/execution env?